Anchor detecting wrong Rust version
Anchor keeps detecting my Rust version as 1.68.0-dev even though it is the newest one, any idea?
jano@Jans-MacBook-Pro counter_2 % anchor test
warning: /Users/jano/Desktop/projekty/programowanie/soldevCourse/firstanchor/counter_2/programs/counter_2/Cargo.toml: unused manifest key: package.rustc
error: package solana-program v1.18.17 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.17 --precise ver
where ver is the latest version of solana-program supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev
jano@Jans-MacBook-Pro counter_2 % rustc --version
rustc 1.79.0 (129f3b996 2024-06-10)
jano@Jans-MacBook-Pro counter_2 %

The solana tool suite doesn't use the system's rustc compiler but instead ships with it's own version of rustc.
The latest version ship with the latest-ish version and updating your solana tool suite solana-install update should help with this

package solana-program v1.18.12 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer error
Run cargo add solana-program@"=1.18.x", where x matches your version of solana-cli. Then re-run anchor build.

sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.18.17/install)"
